# Why are these images moving positions when I drag the window to different sizes?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am building a website for a client and I am struggling with some images that are moving positions as I move the window screen to different sizes.  I want these images to stay exactly where they are.

Here is the code.  The ** refers to the pictures that are moving

HTML

```
<div id="header">                
    **<div id="pics">
        <img id ="jaytext" src="newImages/jaycousins.png">**
        <img  id="papa" src="newImages/papaPic.jpg">
        **<img id ="darkTextBackground" src="newImages/darktextbackgroubd.jpg">**
        **<img id ="commercialtext" src="newImages/commercialtext.png">**
        <img id ="leftsidebackground" src="newImages/leftsidebackground.jpg">           
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: url(../newImages/headerBackground.jpg) repeat;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    //font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
        min-height: 800px;
        max-height: 800px;
        min-width: 1280px;
        max-width: 1289px;

}

#header {
    background: url(../images/bg-header.png) repeat-x bottom center;
    margin: 0;  
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        height:290px;  //height for adjust picture

}
#papa {
    display: block;     
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 430px;
        margin-left:0px;           
        height:270px;    
}
#jaytext{
    width:470px;
    height:110px;

    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top:5.5%;
    left:31.5%;

}
#darkTextBackground{
     margin: 0 auto;

    width:550px;
    height:73px;
    position:absolute;
        top:24.2%;
        left:31.8%; 

}
#commercialtext{
     margin: 0 auto;

    height:53px;
    width:505px;
    position:absolute;
           top:23.7%;
           left:31.70%;

}
#leftsidebackground{
    display: block;     
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
    left:-40%;
}
```

I thought adding the min/max-width min/max-height in the body would fix it...

Comment: can you explain more specifically what do you mean by **"moving"** and **"staying exactly where they are"** ? where exactly are they moving, and where do you want them to stay? in same x,y coordinates relatively to viewport, or what?

Comment: When the window screen changes sizes, the image moves with the screen vs staying static to where it originally was placed.  Its hard to really explain.  The two of the images are text.  So when I adjust the size of the screen(smaller) those text images adjust with the screen.

Comment: i think it would be easier if you could make pictures of initial state - faulty outcome - desired outcome, or recreate the issue in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) where we can see it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mzwuuvyg/   This really doesn't show much...but those smaller rectangle images will move as the screen size width becomes larger or smaller..

Comment: why not just set their position to fixed/absolute then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#header{
 position:relative;/*or absolute*/
}
or
#pics{
 position:relative;/*or absolute*/
}
would help you!
```

the moving images have 'position' set to 'absolute'.This causes your problem.An 'absolute' element's position is determined by its 'containing block'. 'Containing Block' for an 'absolute' element is the nearest 'positioned' ancestor, which means the ancestor has 'position' set to 'relative or absolute or fixed ' but not 'stacitc'. [reference on containing block](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning)

[other reference](http://www.cnblogs.com/JosephLiao/)

Comment: then..would you chose my answer , so I can gain reputations? I need it..Thanks

Comment: Oh bro, I tried, but apparently I need 15 just to vote up someones answer...sorry man\

Comment: What you need to do is click the 'hook' icon at the begining of my anwser under the number...